# How to split strings in data frame and put comma as delimiter

Tags: pandas

I have below data frame using Pandas:

```
    a   b
1   AC  GA
2   AT  AA
3   GG  TG
4   GC  GA
5   CG  GG
```

and I would like to split each string and put comma as delimiter:

```
         a  b
    1   A,C G,A
    2   A,T A,A
    3   G,G T,G
    4   G,C G,A
    5   C,G G,G
```

any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `stack`/`unstack`

```
df.stack().str.join(',').unstack()

     a    b
1  A,C  G,A
2  A,T  A,A
3  G,G  T,G
4  G,C  G,A
5  C,G  G,G
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `applymap(",".join)`

**Ex:**

```
df = df.applymap(",".join)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     a    b
0  A,C  G,A
1  A,T  A,A
2  G,G  T,G
3  C,G  G,G
```

Comment: This answer is better imo.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
def yfunc(x):
   return x.apply(lambda x : ','.join(list(x)))
df.apply(yfunc)
Out[561]: 
     a    b
1  A,C  G,A
2  A,T  A,A
3  G,G  T,G
4  G,C  G,A
5  C,G  G,G
```